# Adding a border to image control prevents image from displaying WPF

Tags: wpf, image, border

I have a perplexing problem that makes no sense to me - I am trying to place a border round an image control in WPF. The image control displays an image perfectly (I have loaded through code behind and XAML and both work fine). However when I place a border around the image control the image does not appear at all. This happening with three image controls all with identical config. Does anyone know why this is or how I can fix it? Many thanks, Jeff.

XAML (with border commented out) is below:

```
<!--<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="201,172,618,450" Grid.Column="1">-->
                    <Image Name="imgFault11" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="1" Margin="200,172,619,450">

                <!--</Border>-->
```

Comment: see this blog post for a good tutorial http://www.snowball.be/WPF+Tutorial+How+To+Create+Great+Image+Effects+With+WPFXAML.aspx

Comment: do you remove the Image's margins (which are huge, btw)?

Comment: Thanks mcalex I see it was the margins that was causing my problem. Didn't realise that the margin of the image referred to the enclosing border! I have a lot to learn about XAML! And thanks Rachel that link looks great will check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting both in Grid.Column="1"
Put the image in the border
Start with no margins

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="1">
     <Image Name="imgFault11" Stretch="Fill">
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks Blam - that worked. I removed the border from the image (didn't realise the image margin referred to the border) and changed the grid. I have only just started using XAML and to be honest I sometimes wish I stayed with winforms! WPF takes some getting used to!

Answer (score -1):

You may have to send the border to the Background. Once you add this it overlays the image. Right click the border .. go to order and then choose "Send to Back". The border control is in the toolbox. This is all a little messy though as getting the border to match the image box size takes time to get right and then you have one control on top of another..etc.